# How to remove the symbols in numbers from the application in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am new to windows phone development. I have created one windows phone 8 application. **When I run the application in emulator, it is showing some symbols on the emulator top right corner. Please find those in the below picture, which marked with red rectangle.**
  [image]

**I think that those symbols only come in emulator. Now I have deployed the application on the device. Then also those symbols are coming in every page of my application.**

Please help me how to remove those symbols from my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your App.xaml.cs file.

Look for this code:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // Display the current frame rate counters.
    Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
    ...
```

Comment out the line

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

or set it to false.